# Imagemagick - Inverse

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I've a png image containing transparent pixels and colored pixels (mainly white).

I'd like to transform all transparent pixels to white pixels and all white pixels to transparent pixels within a given rectangle.

My idea would be to

1. convert the white pixels to red
2. the transparent colors to white
3. and the red colors to transparent

. Here' s my code:

```
1) convert ldl_0.png -fuzz 10% -fill red -opaque white lx.png
2) convert lx.png -background white -alpha remove -alpha off lx2.png
```

However I can' t figure out how do I transform red colors to transparent. How do I do that?

Also how can I force to do this only within a given rectangle?

Thank You.

-----[image: Test Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in ImageMagick. Negate the alpha channel and turn the whole RGB channels to white.

```
convert in.png -channel a -negate +channel -fill white -colorize 100 out.png
```

Comment: Well, it sets everything to white. If I change white to transparent, it sets everything to transparent, which is required, but I need to set only the red colors to background color. How can I do that? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Post an image that can be used to demonstrate and explain what you want for the result.

Comment: I added a test image file to the original question. I'd like to have the text "For Test" with transparent color, and everything else with white color. So swap white and background.

Comment: Try `convert test.png -fill white -colorize 100 -channel a -negate +channel out.png`

Comment: Wow, thanks. It works fine and I don't need 3 steps, only one.

Comment: One more question maybe: can I somehow direct "this behaviour" into a reactangle, so it'll swap the color only within a given area?

Comment: Post and example image and I will try to help. But it should work for any transparent area on white image.

Comment: The image can be the same which is posted already. My goal is to do this "swap" for instance only for 700x300+200+200 geometry, so not for all the image, just some part of it.

Comment: On ImageMagick 6 or ImageMagick 7?

Comment: On ImageMagick 6, you can do `convert test.png +repage -fill white -colorize 100 -channel a -region 700x300+200+200 -negate +channel out.png`

Comment: I've ImageMagick v6, and your solution is exactly what I needed. Thanks!